# Работа с виджетом button (Tkinter, python)

Tags: python

Делал простой кликер, так как сам почти полный 0 в сфере программирования.
Проблема: При нажатии на btn4 при определенных условиях должна будет показываться надпись (смотреть код ниже), при другом условии - исполняться команда скрытии btn4. Но ни первое, ни второе, не работает, решение, возможно, искал плохо, как итог - не нашёл.

Ниже написан сам код, некоторые его части взяты и открытых источников в целях обучения своего разгильдяйство

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import Tk, BOTH

from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Style

import tkinter as tk                                # Объявление всех библиотек  (потом добавятся фоны для кнопок и самого окна, поэтому тут заранее объявлены не используемые библиотеки)          

tk = Tk()

tk.title('Clicker')

tk.geometry("1600x2300")

n = 0            # Счетчик кликов

m = 1            # Изменение (прибавка) счетчика кликов

s = 1            # Нужна для открытия кнопок улучшения (функция их скрытия пока в разработке xd)


def nplus():                          # Функция, отвечающая за прибавку к счётчику кликов (переменная m)

    global n
    n = n + m
    label['text'] = str(n) + '₽'

def nsbros():                           # Функция, отвечающая за нажатие кнопки "сброс"

    global n
    n = 0
    label['text'] = str(n) + '₽'

def inr():

    global s
    s = s - 1
    if s == 0:
        def upg():
            if n >= 5:                          # Если кликов больше или равно 5, то, по идее, btn4 должна быть скрыта, а сама при этом выполнить свою функцию прибавки 
                event.widget.pack_forget()
                global m
                m = m + 1
                label['text'] = str(n) + '₽'
            else:
                err = Label(tk, text="У Вас недостаточно денег для повышения дохода", font='Arail 15 bold')       # Иначе будет показана надпись о малом кол-ве кликов
                err.place(x=50, y=200)
    btn4 = Button(tk, font='Arial 15 bold', compound=CENTER, text="Улучшение - 1500 ₽", command=upg)            # Сама кнопка
    btn4.pack()

btn1 = Button(tk, width = 20, height = 5, font='Arial 15 bold', 
        compound=CENTER, text='Клик', command = nplus)                   # Кнопка для клика

btn1.pack()

label = Label(tk, text=str(n)+'₽', font=('Helvetica 100'))                 # Вывод переменной n 
label.pack()                                                                    

btn2 = Button(tk, width = 20, height=5, font='Arial 15 bold', 
        compound=CENTER, text='Сброс', command = nsbros)                    # Кнопка сброса
btn2.pack()

btn3 = Button(tk, width = 20, height=5, font='Arial 15 bold', 
        compound=CENTER, text='Улучшения', command = inr)                   # Кнопка, при нажатии на которую должен появиться первый вариант улучшения для счетчика

btn3.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

В btn4 указана функция, которая находится так скажем на другом уровне доступа (в if), по этому при нажатии на кнопку ничего не произойдёт, т.к. кнопка не имеет доступа к этой функции.

Вынесите функцию upg() за пределы функции inr():

```
def nplus():                          # Функция, отвечающая за прибавку к счётчику кликов (переменная m)

    global n
    n = n + m
    label['text'] = str(n) + '₽'

def nsbros():                           # Функция, отвечающая за нажатие кнопки "сброс"

    global n
    n = 0
    label['text'] = str(n) + '₽'

def upg():
    if n >= 5:
        event.widget.pack_forget()
        global m
        m = m + 1
        label['text'] = str(n) + '₽'
    else:
        err = Label(tk, text="У Вас недостаточно денег для повышения дохода", font='Arail 15 bold')
        err.place(x=50, y=200)

def inr():
...
```

Или же попробуйте поместить btn4 наряду с функцией, которая она должна выполнять:

```
def inr():

    global s
    s = s - 1
    if s == 0:
        def upg():
            if n >= 5:                          # Если кликов больше или равно 5, то, по идее, btn4 должна быть скрыта, а сама при этом выполнить свою функцию прибавки 
                event.widget.pack_forget()
                global m
                m = m + 1
                label['text'] = str(n) + '₽'
            else:
                err = Label(tk, text="У Вас недостаточно денег для повышения дохода", font='Arail 15 bold')       # Иначе будет показана надпись о малом кол-ве кликов
                err.place(x=50, y=200)
        btn4 = Button(tk, font='Arial 15 bold', compound=CENTER, text="Улучшение - 1500 ₽", command=upg)            # Сама кнопка
        btn4.pack()
```

И ещё кое что:
вместо

```
event.widget.pack_forget()
```

лучше напишите

```
btn4.pack_forget()
```

Comment: Я бы Вам пивка Тархуна купил, реально, спасибо большое. Дай бог Вам здоровья, денег, любви, счастья, благосостояния :3

Comment: Незачто) Всегда рад помочь :>